# Python Requests failed to provide entire response

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently learning web scraping. Today I tried to web scrape google.com searches. When i tried to make get requests with python requests library, it doesn't provide me entire response.

For Example, if I call this URL https://www.google.com/search?q=tea+meaning to get the meaning to the word tea, then in the resulting response it shows noun content alone and not verb content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as req

headers_Get = {
    'Host': 'www.google.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/74.0.3729.169 Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=tea+meaning"
response = req.get(url, headers=headers_Get)

data = response.text
soup = bs(data, "html.parser")
```

Here the problem is with this soup. It doesn't contain verb content.
Why this happens?

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: what is verb content?

Comment: It doesn't contain verb content , what do you mean by verb content?

Comment: print(soup.prettify())

Comment: it is entire response.

Comment: Tea is not a verb, so...?

Comment: I have added a image showing verb content. I can scrap for noun content but verb content is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Google isn't sending back the search results as one page. Most of the things you see in the browser as search results are separate AJAX requests. You might get some partial data in the initial request, but it will not necessarily match the things seen from a regular browser.

To get an idea of what you would see with Beautiful Soup and Requests, try opening the link in a browser with JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You should select which `<div>` to print .You're getting the whole page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=tea+meaning"
header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36'}
page=requests.get(url,headers=header)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
result = soup.select_one('div.vmod').get_text()
print(result)
```

This code prints everything including the verbs.
And hey if you want to get meanings there is a good API at https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/ try using it

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's because on the US site this meaning isn't displayed for some reason.
But you can make it work by changing country query `gl` `param` for the Google search, for example, to the United Kingdom.

You can pass query `params` like so:

```py
params = {
  "q": "tea meaning",  # query
  "gl": "uk"           # country to make search from
}
requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

If you want to get just *one* definition, use `select_one()`:

```py
word_meaning = soup.select_one(".sY7ric .sY7ric span").text
print(word_meaning)
# a hot drink made by infusing the dried crushed leaves of the tea plant in boiling water.
```

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "tea meaning",
  "gl": "uk"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

word_meaning = soup.select_one(".sY7ric .sY7ric span").text
print(word_meaning)

# a hot drink made by infusing the dried crushed leaves of the tea plant in boiling water.
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to do anything related to picking the right selector or maintain the parser over time since it's already done for the end-users. And you only need to get the data you want from the structured JSON string.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "tea meaning",
    "gl": "uk",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

word_meaning = results['answer_box']['definitions']
print(word_meaning)

---------
'''
# list of definitions:
[
'a hot drink made by infusing the dried crushed leaves of the tea plant in boiling water.', 
'the dried leaves used to make tea.', 
'a hot drink made from the infused leaves, fruits, or flowers of other plants.',
'the evergreen shrub or small tree that produces tea leaves, native to South and eastern Asia and grown as a major cash crop.'
]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.